# asp.net handle a get request from outside

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am using an sms gateway where I need to handle messages being sent to 'me'.

The documentation states that when a user sends an sms to me I will get parameters like this:

```
http://server.domain.tld/receive.php?MOBILE=4560512131&TEXT=keyword+hello+world&SHORTCODE=1290&SMSC=tdc&MSGID=
```

Where `http://server.domain.tld/receive.php?` should be on my server

I am not using php so I need to be able to get these parameters using asp.net (mobile, text, shortcode, smsc, msgid)

My website currently has WebAPI implemented and I use ASP.NET MVC5 framework, but I am not sure what to do. How do I get the incoming parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an action similar to this:

```
public string Receive(string MOBILE, string TEXT, string SHORTCODE, string SMSC, string MSGID)
    {
        // just handle your variables here: save to database, log, email, etc...

        return "OK"; // just an example, it depends on what the gateway is expecting
    }
```

And assuming this resides inside the Home controller, there should be a way to specify this "callback URL" to the gateway. This URL should be:

```
http://[your website]/home/receive
```

If your SMS gateway documentation is not clear enough about how to change/configure this URL, just drop them an email.

Comment: This works for me and I'm able to get the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you must parse url encoded string using for example NameValueCollection and then pass this data to you Controller for further procesing.
Accept url encoded string in GET or POST of Controller not that difficult as well.
Like this jQuery + WebApi example where Controller accept in POST action url encoded string.

```
 $("#searchbtn").click(function () {
                var ser = $('#hotels').find('input, select').serialize();
                $.post('/api/hotelsavailablerq', { '': ser });
            });
```

And server side:

```
public void PostHotelsAvailableRQ([FromBody] string q)
        {
           NameValueCollection qscoll = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(q);
           //Process key-value pairs
        }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Where would that JavaScript be going? I doubt they enable JavaScript in the SMS service's webhooks, and I *especially* doubt that anyone sits there clicking "search." I'm also not sure what hotels have anything to do with the original question.

Comment: This is exmaple of the code that I would use for this situation.

Comment: Matthew, look at the answer that OP accept as correct answer. What you said it's event not close to this. OP asking how to handle this with MVC cotroller, not with HttpHandler.

Comment: That's why I deleted my answer. It turned out that the asker was able to change settings, and the disclosed premise of mine was that it was only relevant if that wasn't possible. The accepted answer is far preferable, now that we know that isn't the case. There's no need to get defensive, I was only trying to understand your solution and how it would fit the asker's needs. I wasn't the person that down-voted you. Perhaps that was whomever up-voted my comment.

Comment: Ok, let me explain. OP probably must call some external web service that inform about incoming sms message. This means that should be some JSON or XML or URL encoded string, any kind of message with parameters that are for further processing. Otherwise how he knows about this event happend? And this means that he has some incoming information that able to be parsed by MVC Controller for example (same as JQuery actually). Anyway, both of us gave answser that not suites to OP needs. Pity.